# Sitecore Experience Editor with JSS SDK

Tags: jss

We have a requirement of using Angular page along with Sitecore 9 JSS SDK. There are two components on the Angular page where first component gets data from Sitecore and other pulls data from API.

Content author should have the option to edit the CMS content of the component.

I have done a small POC with Integrated mode. My question is there any other way to achieve the above requirement?

Comment: Can you provide more details around your requirement(s)? They're a bit unclear at the moment. Are there any specific challenges you're encountering? Does your PoC work or are there specific issues making it work?